# Where can I ask this question? "How can I insert a row if the row is not already present in sql server?"

Tags: support

I want to ask this question.

I have a query which I have written to insert if the row doesn't exist in sql server.

```
insert into Attributes (Id, Disabled, AttributeValue) 
values (@id, @disabled, @attr_value)
if not exists
(
select * from Attributes
where 
Id = @id
)
```

1. Not sure, if this is a valid query.
2. I have seen people use where not exists. What is the difference and how to use where not exists? When I put "**where not exists**", it is saying "Incorrect syntax near where."

Comment: For one thing, you shouldn't be formatting a list as a code block.

Comment: Either stackoverflow or [dba.se] probably but it's a duplicate: [Only inserting a row if it's not already there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407857/only-inserting-a-row-if-its-not-already-there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have http://dba.stackexchange.com for Database Administrators. [It's FAQ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq) states that;

> If you have a question about...
>
> 1. Database Administration including configuration and backup/restore
> 2. Advanced Querying including window-functions dynamic-sql and query-performance
> 3. Data Modelling and database-design including referential-integrity
> 4. Advanced Programming in built-in server-side languages including stored-procedures and triggers.
> 5. Data Warehousing and Business Intelligence including etl reporting and olap
>
> ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!
>
> but, dba.se is *not* the right place to ask questions about...
>
> 1. Client-side programming - ask on Stack Overflow
> 2. **Basic SQL - ask on Stack Overflow**
> 3. Career advice, including salary or résumé - try Patrick McKenzie's Don't call yourself a programmer

So **ultimately**, your question should be posted on ***StackOverflow***.

Comment: This could be on topic for [dba.se] if the OP wanted an answer addressing concurrency issues but seems that probably they are just asking about syntax...

Comment: Not relevant to question but, 
Career advice, including salary or résumé - try Patrick McKenzie's Don't call yourself a programmer - means it should be also posted on Stackoverflow right?

Comment: @tech_learner: No, see http://www.kalzumeus.com/2011/10/28/dont-call-yourself-a-programmer/

Comment: @MartinSmith: Indeed, but given the snippet of the question posted in the OP, I'd classify it as a "basic SQL" question.

Comment: @tech: No, career advice is off-topic for Stack Overflow.